# Heroku html subpages in node js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, heroku

Hello im fresh with programing I start making my simple portfolio in heroku
and problem is with subpages i dont know how to add new subpage to my portfolio i always get Cannot GET /frontend.ejs

link to my portfolio:
http://poninsky.herokuapp.com

i dont have to much knowledge about node js

this is code from index.js what i get from heroku what i need to chenge for add subpages :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
response.render('pages/index');
});
app.get('/frontend', function(request, response) {
response.render('pages/frontend');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

thanks for answers!

After run i get this :

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Desktop/test/node-js-getting-started 
/index.js:1:77)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

npm ERR! Linux 4.12.0-kali1-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run-script" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4 
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-js-getting-started@0.2.6 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-js-getting-started@0.2.6 start script 'node                
index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm   
installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-js- 
getting-started package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project   
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-js-getting-started
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-js-getting-started
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean   
to install? '
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/Desktop/test/node-js-getting-started/npm-debug.log
Done.
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`? try `npm install` first

Comment: hey when i put npm install i get this answer: npm WARN node-js-getting-started@0.2.6 No repository field.

Comment: It doesn't matter... it means that you don't specify some filed in your package.json. Try to run the App.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely a couple of issues at work here, the first and most important being that it doesn't look like your dependencies have installed. Does your project have a `package.json` with all your dependencies, like Express, listed? Heroku installs whatever's listed in that section of the package manifest; make sure to also specify your `engines` (i.e. Node and version) so Heroku knows what Node version to use.

When you access your endpoints, don't put `.ejs` at the end of them either. EJS is only used as the view engine and compiles to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes project have package.json in here is inside :

```
{
"name": "node-js-getting-started",
"version": "0.2.6",
"description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
"engines": {
"node": "6.11.1"
},
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"test": "node test.js"
},
"dependencies": {
"ejs": "2.5.6",
"express": "4.15.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"request": "^2.81.0",
"tape": "^4.7.0"
},

"keywords": [
"node",
"heroku",
"express"
],
"license": "MIT"
}
```